# Google Maps Android api Indoor Routing

Tags: android, google-maps, indoor-positioning-system

I have a problem: I need to calculate the routing within a mall that has a plan registered in google maps, but with the direction API can not get the indoor routing. To be precise if I am away from the mall and I want to calculate the route to an internal area, I am guided to the outside of the mall, while I would like my app would calculate a route for the section inside the building . To do this I currently use the Google Maps Android API v2 and the Direction api with json output. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? sorry for my bad English

Comment: can share the idea here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449261/indoor-map-upload-status-is-reviewed-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem; compting a route (with mode=walking) between two points that are both *inside* a mall gives a path that starts, goes and ends *out* of the building.

The closest similar path found on Google Maps (HTML version, from a browser) is the "bike" one...